# Inside a branch of a match block, how do I use the assertion that the matched expression is equal to the branch's data constructor expression?

Tags: coq

I am trying to develop a programming style that is based on preventing bad input as soon as possible. For example, instead of the following plausible definition for the predecessor function on the natural numbers:

```
Definition pred1 n :=
  match n with
    | O   => None
    | S n => Some n
  end.
```

I want to write it as follows:

```
Theorem nope n (p : n = O) (q : n <> O) : False.
  contradict q.
  exact p.
Qed.

Definition pred2 n (q : n <> O) :=
  match n with
    | S n => n
    | O   =>
      let p := _ in
      match nope n p q with end
  end.
```

But I have no idea what to replace `_` with. My intuition suggests me that there must be some `assumption : n = O` available in the `| O =>` branch. Does Coq indeed introduce such an assumption? If so, what is its name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coq doesn't automatically introduce such hypothesis, but you can introduce it explicitly by using the full form of the `match` construction:

```
Definition pred2 n (q : n <> O) :=
  match n as n' return n = n' -> nat with
    | S p => fun _ => p
    | O   => fun Heq => match q Heq with end
  end (eq_refl n).
```

Explanations:

- `return` introduces a type annotation with the type of the whole `match ... end` expression;
- `as` introduces a variable name that can be used in this type annotation and will be substituted with the left hand side in each branch. Here,

  - in the first branch, the right hand side has type `n = S p -> nat`;
  - in the second branch, the right hand side has type `n = O -> nat`. Therefore, `q Heq` has type `False` and can be matched.

More information in the [reference manual](http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/refman/), in the chapter on [Extended pattern-matching](http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/refman/Reference-Manual022.html).

Comment: It seems to me that we have shifted the problem of introducing the assumption that `n = O` in the `| O =>` branch to the problem of introducing the assumption that `n = n'` at the level of the whole match block. This shows in your `pred2`'s return type, which is not the same as that of mine.

Comment: It seems that Stéphane forgot to pass in the proof: just after the last `end`, add `(eq_refl n)` to pass in the argument of type `n = n''`.